# symfony: How to change a sfCoreAutoloader class path?

Tags: caching, symfony1, overriding, config, autoloader

I want symfony to use my own sfConfigCache.class.php, but I don't know how to modify the default path in the autoloader array. Or is there another way to tell symfony to use my class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I extended the sfApplicationConfiguration:

*myproject/apps/frontend/lib/sfApplicationConfigurationExtended .class.php*

```
class sfApplicationConfigurationExtended extends sfApplicationConfiguration
{
  public function getConfigCache()
  {
    if (null === $this->configCache)
    {
      $this->configCache = new sfConfigBlobCache($this);
    }

    return $this->configCache;
  }
}
```

*myproject/apps/frontend/config/frontendConfiguration.class.php*

```
class frontendConfiguration extends sfApplicationConfiguration #sfApplicationConfigurationExtended // For config blob caching
{
  public function configure()
  {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may find [this](http://www.symfony-project.org/more-with-symfony/1_4/en/14-Playing-with-Symfony-Config-Cache#chapter_14_the_config_cache) helpful.

Explains how to customize the configCache.

Comment: Thx, but this is just about using the config cache for own yml files and not about manipulating the config cache e.g. to implement another storage type.

Comment: Sorry. I was hoping it would of been useful.